# Are there any differences in the garbage collector for vb.net and c#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, garbage-collection

I've heard that the c# garbage collector can be 'more aggressive' than it's vb.net counterpart.  Is this true?  Are there any other differences in how garbage collection is run in vb.net vs. c#?

Comment: I would expect there to not be any difference as it's a runtime CLR thing and CLR shouldn't [theoretically] even know or care what the program was written in.  Of course the reality might differ significantly.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I had thought as well, but I've heard this enough times to make me wonder if I was incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's my understanding that the CLR maintains garbage collection and is not language-specific.

Answer (score 6):

The garbage collector in the CLR is the same.  The difference that people are referring to probably lies in the syntax of the languages.  In VB.NET you can probably have language structures that cause references to objects to unexpectedly hang around longer, resulting in objects that are not GC-eligible as early as they might be in C#.  This is all conjecture though.

Comment: Conjecture, yes. But still the most likely answer so far.

Answer (score 5):

The garbage collector is part of the common language runtime (CLR) and provides memory management across all languages that use the CLR - it is not language specific.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between the garbage collector for C# or VB. This is part of the CLR and is shared across all languages. However, there *is* a difference between the garbage collector running on servers vs workstations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx#workstation_and_server_garbage_collection

Answer (score 1):

The garbage-collector itself is the same.  There is, however, a difference in the way finalizers are handled.  In vb.net, one overrides `Object.Finalize()` by simply declaring `Sub Overrides Finalize()`.  Any code in that routine will override `Object.Finalize`.  In C#, overriding `Object.Finalize()` is forbidden.  Instead, one has to use a syntax construct which is ironically called a "destructor" (even though prevents an object from being destroyed immediately when it otherwise would), which overrides `Finalize()` with the following:

```
override void Finalize(void)
{
  try
  {
    .. supplied code here
  }
  finally
  {
    base.Finalize();
  }
}
```

The supposed purpose of the language construct is to make finalization code be platform-independent.  In practice, it's just a silly nuisance, since any code which uses finalizers *correctly* will have to use platform-specific methods like `GC.KeepAlive()` and `GC.SuppressFinalize()`.